# Highlighting CamelCase in WebStorm

Tags: webstorm, camelcasing

Is there any possibility to play with editor setting in order to achieve that ?

I would like to see if there is an option to highlight the Camel Cased letters, with different color or different brightness.

Comment: There is no such setting. CamelCased name of function/variable/etc is no different to snake_one or any other style.

Comment: hi @LazyOne , thank for your answer.

i think it would be nice feature.

Comment: WebStorm Issue Tracker where you can file Feature Request tickets is located here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB